# Ordinal-definable witnesses to the perfect set property?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, inner-model-theory, determinacy

*This possibly a very basic descriptive set-theory question; if it is too basic for MO, feel free to migrate.*

Throughout we work in ZF+AD. My question is:

> If $A$ is an uncountable OD set of reals, need $A$ have an OD perfect subset?

Motivation: The *Solovay sequence* is given by:

- $\theta_0$ is the least ordinal onto which $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't surject via an OD function;
- $\theta_\lambda=\sup\{\theta_\alpha: \alpha<\lambda\}$ for $\lambda$ limit; and
- $\theta_{\alpha+1}$ is the least ordinal onto which $\mathcal{P}(\theta_\alpha)$ doesn't surject via an OD function.

Ignore the later stages of the hierarchy; if the answer to my question is no, then we get a potentially interesting way to compare the "size" of two uncountable sets of reals under AD (which of course have cardinality continuum): let $\theta_0(X)$ be the least ordinal onto which $X$ doesn't surject in an OD way. If the answer to my question is "no," we might have $\theta_0(X)<\theta_0$ for some uncountable $X$, even assuming AD. This looks very interesting to me.

. . . which is why I think the answer to my question will be "yes" :P. But oh well.

(To keep going and define $\theta_\alpha(X)$, we need $X$ to be "ordinal-independent": that is, we want a "$\kappa$-version" $X_\kappa\subseteq 2^\kappa$ of $X$ for all (or enough) $\kappa$s. Then we can talk about things like the rate at which the Solovay sequence grows, for a given such $X$; but I think I'm getting well ahead of myself, so I'll stop for now.)

---

A note on tags: I used the inner-model-theory tag because of the importance of the Solovay sequence in descriptive inner model theory, and more generally the hope that inner model theory might be relevant to this question. This might be incorrect on my part; if so, feel free to remove that tag.

Comment: A guess: let X be the OD set of all Cohen generic reals over L. It would be strange to get an OD surjection X onto even $\omega_2^L$ - ?

Comment: @VladimirKanovei That seems promising!Maybe add it to my other question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243461/comparing-the-sizes-of-uncountable-sets-of-reals-under-ad if you can resolve it further?

Comment: I am thinking more about the choiceless Solovay model, where my conjecture would look like a sure fact.

Comment: @VladimirKanovei See my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243461/comparing-the-sizes-of-uncountable-sets-of-reals-under-ad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of those reals that are *not* OD.  Then $A$ is OD (since I've just defined it), and it's uncountable (since its complement, being a well-orderable set of reals, must be countable under AD). But any perfect OD set $P$ has an element that is OD and thus outside $A$, namely the first element of $P$
(in the usual ordering of the reals, or, if your reals are $2^\omega$, in the lexicographic order), which exists as $P$ is compact.  That first element is OD because it's defined from the OD set $P$.

Comment: Very nice! I forgot that "ordinal definable" was ordinal definable :P. Given this, do you know if it's possible for an uncountable OD set $X$ to have $\theta_0(X)<\theta_0$?

Comment: EDIT: "Possible" should of course be "possible *under AD*."

Comment: I like the answer a lot. Meanwhile, let me point out that Andreas's set has a perfect subset definable from a real, in fact, from any non-OD real $z$. If you fix $z$, consider the set of reals whose even-bits form a copy of $z$.

Comment: I've asked a new question based on my comments/motivation here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/243461/comparing-the-sizes-of-uncountable-sets-of-reals-under-ad.